# Wrong non-zero sizes on glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES

Tags: ipad, ios5, opengl-es, framebuffer, layoutsubviews

This is similar to another question that was on stackoverflow but the sizes there were `0,0` and here I am getting wrong strange non zero sizes.  So it appears that this might qualify as a different problem.

The problem happens when I am configuring the framebuffer in layoutSubviews.

```
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
```

When this call returns the sizes I am getting are `1139` (`backingHeight`) x `841` (`backingWidth`).

These sizes look really strange as they don't correspond to any standard dimensions that I know of.

The ipad is oriented to portrait mode.  The stack begins with `layoutSubviews`.  I read a few earlier threads and decided to postpone the call to later when `layoutSubviews` might have finished stablilizing the view.  But even if I delay the framebuffer creation to the display link callback the values show no improvement and are still `1139` (h) x `841` (w).

Also if I examine the bounds size on UIScreen `mainScreen` in the debugger I get 1024x768.

```
(lldb) print ((CGRect)[[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ]).size.height
(CGFloat) $0 = 1024
(lldb) print ((CGRect)[[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ]).size.width
(CGFloat) $1 = 768
```

So somehow it appears that these bounds are not carrying forward to the `backingWidth` and `backingHeight` of the OpenGL EAGLayer.  The framebuffer still gets created , but my content is based on the wrong (larger) size and goes off the screen.

I am on xcode 4.5.2 and the ipad is on iOS 5.1.1. I will continue to track this down, but there is not much to go by.

Comment: Some more additional data, the layer.frame also carries the incorrect dimensions
(lldb) print self.layer.frame

(CGRect) $3 = origin=(x=0, y=20) size=(width=841, height=1139)

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some more research and figured that if frame.layer is carrying the wrong size, then I guessed that it might not be a transfer of size problem between the frame and opengl.

The problem was in the xib file.

I pulled open the xib, went to window, => view and pulled open the size inspector.  There the sizes were wrong , so the mouse may have inadvertently dragged the view in the xib.  It was a trivial error, but that was the source of the problem - I corrected the xib and now it works fine. This took more than a few hours to diagnose what was actually a simple fix, but I kept diagnosing the code and not the xib. The window carries the right size in the xib (1024, 768) and this is grayed so xcode won't allow you to modify this, but the view sizes can be modified and the view had been mistakenly sized to be larger than the window. So I manually matched the view sizes to the window size.

Thanks to anyone who might have tried to figure this out.